# Compilation error Overloaded method value [apply]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make CRUD operation. When i'm trying to make the edit i got this compilation error:

`Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (Product with Serializable)`

Here is my edit code:

```
def editEvent(id: Int) = Action {
    Evenement.findById(id).map {
      evenement =>
        Ok(html.user.eventEditForm(id, eventForm.fill(evenement)))
    }.getOrElse(notFound)
  }
```

Can someone explain to me this error so i can try to fix it ?

Comment: Could you paste the *whole* compilation error? Apply could potentially  be either the whole body under Action or the apply method that Ok defines. PS: Shouldn't the getOrElse return NotFound (capital N)?

Comment: That's the whole compilation error and it was due to `notFound` I changed it to `NotFound` (capital N) and it worked fine. Thank you.